# Idiomatic way to declare local functions in C

Tags: c, naming

My small program consists of several "modules" - translation units. Some of the entities are `extern`, but others are `static`.

For the external entities, I always put a prefix. The internal ones you can tell by the `static` in front. Still, I am looking for a naming convention that *clearly conveys that the entity is*

- file-specific, not visible from the outside
- can be safely changed without risk of changing api-s
- if there is no static in front, this is a mistake.

Python programmers use a leading underscore. What do C-programmers do?

Comment: A controversial statement, @P0W. In anycase, don't use leading underscores: they are reserved (for, amongst others, the compiler).

Comment: You can do it like Go: Start "exported" function names with capital letter, and static ones with a lower case letter.

Comment: Python way is *convention* of using leading underscore, in c, it if you use `static`, the compiler restricts access to the symbol to current translation unit. You can use whatever convention you like, in fact, a leading underscore is quite intuitive to me.

Comment: @Kninung *double* leading underscore is reserved

Comment: Prefix the exported function names, and don't prefix internal ones. Then just use `static`. That indicates that 1. a symbol is local to a file; 2. that, consequently, can be changed without breaking the API; 3. and if there's `static`, *but* then suddenly there's **no** `static`, that's a terrible mistake because you went either mad or back to the past against your will.

Comment: @P0W Worst advice ever.

Comment: @H2CO3 just kidding, frankly I didn't get the question, I thought OP needs some OO concept, and needless to mention I used **:D** at end ;)

Comment: @H2CO3, C11, 7.1.3 says: _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ This means that a name such as `_name` will (should) never be exposed to your file by any header (or during link) and I believe it would also mean that it's ok if you use it in a file, if you make sure it's contained just to that file.

Comment: @Shahbaz Aham, so that's a change. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @H2CO3, it's the same in C99, too. I admit the wording is a bit vague, but that has been my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Many things, but avoid leading underscores as that is magic in several environments.

Comment: I think one underscore is okay and two is problematic?

Comment: After working in as many operating systems and compilers as I have I simply avoid leading and trailing underscores. Regardless of the any local "best practices" I'm working on I work to avoid simple words in any variable or function name for, if you move the same code across different environments, you never know what #define is going to bite you.  Some type of prefix helps here.

Answer (score 1):

The `static` declaration conveys what you are asking about.  Naturally, it misses this requirement:

> if there is no static in front, this is a mistake.

But I would argue that's a silly requirement. You say you use `_` in Python, which from the standpoint of the safety of building one file (in C, "compiling one translation unit"), is strictly inferior. If you omit it, Python won't notice until runtime, and the behavior won't change. Maybe you need another requirement in Python to alert the reader that a `_` may be missing. How about `__`? But what if *that* is missing? And so forth. What if your program doesn't terminate and it's supposed to? You can't write a ["does it stop"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) check.

And in any case, in my experience, C developers don't actually worry about this. If it helps you read, it would not be unreasonable to make up your own and stick with it when sensible. Maybe `s_` for static, `m_` for module, `t_` for translation unit, etc. These sorts of prefix I think are a weak "meta-convention" in C and C++ for special classes of variables, e.g. class members.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against coding `static` into function names. Why? Because the name should convey what the function is used for in a clear and concise manner. Where it is stored, and where it is accessable is generally of no importance to convey.

Note that this argument is specific to `static` on functions. It does not apply to other things like `const` on *variable* names (I personally use a `k`-prefix for those), or global variables (which should be avoided by all means in the first place).

Comment: I concur.  The "Idiomatic way to declare local functions in C" is to use `static`, not to create a parallel naming convention on function and variable name to do the same thing.